# Webアプリケーションにおける閲覧回数のカウント方法

Tags: sql

例えばメルカリでは、各商品の累計閲覧回数がカウントされていて、自分が出品した商品についてはそれを参照することができます。
この閲覧回数の永続化でパッと思い浮かぶのは、商品閲覧のたびに直前の閲覧回数をRDBから取得し、それをカウントアップしてRDBに保存するという手段です。
しかし、メルカリのような多くのユーザーを抱えるサービスでこの方法を採用すると、単位時間あたり大量のSQLが発行されてしまいパフォーマンス上の問題があると思います。

上記の方法以外で、よく採用される閲覧回数のカウント方法がありましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

要件次第です。

- 信頼性
- リアルタイム性
- アクセス頻度
- 単純にカウントアップすれば良いのか、何か条件はあるのか
- かけられるコスト

例えば時々ログを集計して更新すればすむような用途に複雑な仕組みを入れるのはナンセンスです。

前提なしの単なる「よく使われる手法を教えてください」だと各自が思いついた回答が雑多に集まるだけになってしまうので、具体的な条件を前提にした質問にしたほうがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

どのような環境なのかによって選択できる手段は変わってくると思いますが
一般的な LAMP 環境を想定するとして、NOSQL の memcache を
利用するのはいかがでしょうか ?

[Memcached::increment](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/memcached.increment.php)

Comment: ありがとうございます、LAMP環境を想定することで問題ありません。memcacheで調べてみると同じような質問が見つかりました。memcacheにある程度溜めて、まとめてRDBに更新する手法があるのですね。　https://teratail.com/questions/30993?link=qa_related_pc

Answer (score 1):

同一ユーザーの閲覧は除外するのでカあればウントアップだけじゃ実現できないと思うので。
たぶんRDBでも良いんじゃないでしょうか。

そもそも商品閲覧でもログインユーザーのアクセスでも、常に大量のSQLは発行されてるはずですよね。